# How to calculate percentage between two numbers using SQL on BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Since there is no build-in SQL function that can calculate percentage diffrance between two numbers I want to write the calculation in my own query.

The calculation is:

[image]

As listed [here](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/percent-difference-calculator.php)

This is my query:

```
     select 
    ( ( cast ( 30.245358139534886 - 25.92631649122807  ) as FLOAT64 )
     /
   ( (cast ( 30.245358139534886 + 25.92631649122807  ) as FLOAT64) / 2.0)  ) * 100
```

However this doesn't work it gives:

> Syntax error: Unexpected ")" at [3:52]

*Casting is needed as not always numbers will be float.

The result of this query should be: 15.378
[The calculation can be seen here](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/percent-difference-calculator.php?v_1=30.245358139534886&v_2=25.92631649122807&action=solve)

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your specific question why it fails .. you are missing parentheses and using wrong the cast.

```
   select 
     cast ((30.245358139534886 - 25.92631649122807) as FLOAT64 )
     /
   ( (cast ( (30.245358139534886 + 25.92631649122807  ) as FLOAT64) / 2.0)  ) * 100
```

How use cast

```
cast (value as datatype)
```

Comment: missing abs I also missed it in my example but it exist in the formula

Answer (score 2):

Your expression would look like this in BigQuery:

```
select 100 * abs( 30.245358139534886 - 25.92631649122807  ) /
       ( (30.245358139534886 + 25.92631649122807) / 2)
```

Comment: Why This fails?   select 100 * abs( 30.245358139534886 - 25.92631649122807  ) /
       ( (cast (30.245358139534886 + 25.92631649122807) as FLOAT64 ) / 2.0)    At the end this is just an example numbers will be replaced with column names

Comment: select 100 * abs( 30.245358139534886 - 25.92631649122807 ) / ( cast ((30.245358139534886 + 25.92631649122807) as FLOAT64 ) / 2.0)

Answer (score 1):

[Percent Difference](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/blob/master/udfs/community/percentage_difference.sql) and [Percent Change](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/blob/master/udfs/community/percentage_change.sql) are both defined in the big query community utils. Check out the example below!

Percent Difference example:

```
SELECT bqutil.fn.percentage_difference(1, 0.1)
```

Returns

> 1.6364

Percent Change example:

```
SELECT bqutil.fn.percentage_change(1, 0.1)
```

Returns

> 0.9

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select 
( ABS( cast ( 30.245358139534886 - 25.92631649122807  as FLOAT) )
 / ( (cast ( 30.245358139534886 + 25.92631649122807  as FLOAT) ) / 2.0)  ) * 100 FROM DUAL;
```